# jQuery Sliders, how can i exclude 1 slider from a jQuery('.slider').each(function()

Tags: jquery, slider, each

I have 3 sliders that are used calculate a number of MB used online.  The total MB is translated to GB and a total slider is created and adjusted to reflect the total.  I am using a jQuery('.slider').each(function() to find the MB for each slider and then increment the overall total.  However, i have 1 of the sliders that i do not want be included in the each function, can i exclude 1 slider from the .each function?

how i create the sliders:

```
// create the sliders and delegate properties.

  jQuery('#wifi-sl').slider({ min: 0, max: 250,  animate: true, range: 'min', step: 10,
    slide: function (ev, ui) {
     jQuery('#wifi-value').html(ui.value + ' %');
     determineWifi;
    },
    change: function (ev, ui) {
     jQuery('#wifi-value').html(ui.value + ' %');
     determineWifi;
    }
  });

  jQuery('#email-sl').slider({ min: 0, max: 250,  animate: true, range: 'min', step: 10,
    slide: function (ev, ui) {
     jQuery('#email-value').html(ui.value + ' emails');

     determineData();
    },
    change: function (ev, ui) {
     jQuery('#email-value').html(ui.value + ' emails');

     determineData();
    }
  });

  jQuery('#email-sl').slider({ min: 0, max: 250,  animate: true, range: 'min', step: 10,
    slide: function (ev, ui) {
     jQuery('#email-value').html(ui.value + ' emails');
     slider_id='email-sl';
     determineData();
    },
    change: function (ev, ui) {
     jQuery('#email-value').html(ui.value + ' emails');
     slider_id='email-sl';
     determineData();
    }
  });
```

i don't want the top (first) slider to be counted in the each function below, how can i exclude it?

```
function determineData() {

  total_data_mb = 0.00;

  jQuery('.slider').each(function() {
    var this_data = Math.round( jQuery(this).slider('option', 'value') * jQuery(this).data('data')['units'] * jQuery(this).siblings('.per-select').val() * 100) / 100;
    jQuery(this).siblings('.slider-data').html(this_data + ' MB');
    total_data_mb += this_data;
  });

  total_data_gb = (Math.round( (total_data_mb / 1024) * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exclude it,

```
jQuery('.slider').not('#wifi-sl').each(...);
```

or the general case

```
jQuery('.slider').slice(1).each(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the [:not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector in combination with the [:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)  selector

```
    jQuery('.slider:not(:first)').each(function(){
      /* your code */
    });
```

another option is the [sibling selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/)

```
    jQuery('#wifi-sl ~ .slider').each(function(){
      /* your code */
    });
```

Comment: Just note that, `:not` is not available in IE6-8 so for large sets it will be more performant to use `jQuery('.slider').filter(':not(:first)')`

Comment: I agree with that assessment, .filter was going to be another one I put in.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.slider:gt(0)').each(.......
```

Grabs the slider class and starts at index 1